# Error reached while attempting to create a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array[[1,2]]
print x
```

Here's the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Shear_Moment_Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = np.array[[1,2]]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `np.array` is a function, so try `np.array([1,2])` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax which you used is wrong. Use this
`x = np.array([1,2])`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I'm having trouble adding another row:

x = np.array([1,2],[3,4])

produces 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "Shear_Moment_Test.py", line 10, in <module>
        x = np.array([1,2],[3,4])
TypeError: data type not understood

Am I adding the additional data incorrectly?

Comment: A comment and a close vote might be more appropriate, since the error is only due to a typo. I'm voting to close. Please post a new question with your other issue, or have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html first.

Comment: @Benjamin I do not think this is a typo. It is a lack of understanding.  @Matt Moniot When you do `np.array([1, 2], [3, 4])` you are giving two lists to the `np.array` function. However the second positional argument of `np.array` is `dtype`. Therefore you get the error `data type not understood`. For a 2d array, you need to pass a list of lists: `np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`

Comment: Thanks. I'm not very familiar with StackOverflow. I'll do what you said.

Comment: @MaxNoe - thank you! The example I was following only had 1 row. I didn't realize it was a slightly different syntax.

Comment: @MattMoniot, no hurt feelings, but the error/solution will likely not help many people